# Is every First Countable space the continuous image of a Pseudometric space under an open map?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

In Engelking's *General Topology*, Exercise $4.2.\text{D}.(\text{a})$, we are asked to show that a $T_0$ space is $1^{st}$ Countable iff it is the continuous image of a metrizable space under an open mapping. As a metric and pseudometric space differ only by the $T_0$ axiom, this made me wonder - can we remove the $T_0$ axiom and get a result for a pseudometrizable space? That is -

> Is $X$ $1^{st}$ Countable iff it is the continuous image of a pseudometrizable space under an open mapping?

Comment: The $T_0$ was added originally to ensure that the first countable space and the metrisable space have the same weight. If we don't care about that we can drop the $T_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do part (b) of that exercise too, you see that if $X$ is first countable iff $X$ is the open continuous image of a metrisable space. This is theorem 4.3 in [this paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0016660X71900055?token=A4B6B9C345419F7EC51827CF5863A73A487D0169C3679B54B9E4114785EFDD13FFE92D4A25115CEEFE432558BF25D661) by E. Michael.

And it's trivial that if $X$ is the open continuous image of a pseudometrisable space, then it is first countable. So yes, but not for the reason you thought maybe (it has nothing to do with the $T_0$ difference between pseudometrisable and metrisable spaces).